# Copying text in Ionic 2 apps

Tags: ionic2, copy-paste

How can I set up my Ionic 2 app to allow me to select and copy text when inside an app? I have tried with the "user-select: text;" CSS but the app won't allow me to copy text.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that there is some additional CSS needed for a ".selectable" class:

```
.selectable {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```

Doing this and adding class="selectable" to an element will allow users to select and copy text within an app.

http://markwillia.ms/allow-users-select-copy-text-ionic-2-apps/